# How can i use web cookies in android app

Tags: android

I want to use webCookie in in android app. how can i use it?
Situation like this when I were open gmail from my browser  and then logged in it . then in my app webview i want to use same cookies if i opened gmail in webview in app and in app user will be automatically logged in.

Answer (score 0):

To store cookies,

```
CookieSyncManager sManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(myWebView.getContext());
CookieManager cManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

cManager.setCookie(); 
sManager.sync();
```

Comment: Hey thanks Raghu this code useful. let me try first this code is solve my problem or not as mentioned above.